# ggplot() graphical output link broken ./static/post/

Tags: r, bookdown, blogdown

I've followed the advice at https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html by adding a .r file with blogdown::build_dir('static') - and by creating a ./static/post directory - what am I missing?

I also searched through rbind.io blogdown structures, but cannot figure out how to connect rendered graphic outputs to static/post/post-date; not how to automatically redirect outputs to that folder instead of public.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Generally you do not need to handle ggplot output **manually** in blogdown, because blogdown will render the output graphic, put int in static/post/some-where and correctly link it to your post. Could you provide your repo?

Comment: In my local, the plot chunk images are generated in the public folder, but not pushed to the static. I think ive just made 
a mistake somewhere in changing folders https://github.com/pembletonc/blogdown.git

Comment: This is the post, you can see the broken image links as well. http://coreypembleton.netlify.com/random/tidy-text-twitter/

Comment: I think I [found the problem](https://github.com/pembletonc/blogdown/blob/master/static/.gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I [found the problem](https://github.com/pembletonc/blogdown/blob/master/static/.gitignore)

The .gitignore file in your static directory prevents git to stage images generated by blogdown, delete it.

Comment: Cheers, and thank you - deleted it and all works now.